# django - query for the closest numeric value to a given value

Tags: django, absolute

I have a django model Level for a game.

```
class Level(models.Model):

key = models.CharField(max_length=100)
description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
requiredPoints = models.IntegerField()
badgeurl = models.CharField(max_length=100)
challenge = models.ForeignKey(Challenge)
```

I now want to query for the highest level with a pointsRequired value smaller than a given value.

If i have:

Level 1: requiredPoints: 200
Level 2: requiredPoints: 800
Level 3: requiredPoints: 2000

When I enter e.g. 900 or 1999 as a query parameter, I want level 2 to be returned, when entering 10000 it should be level 3.

in sql it would look like

```
select   pointsRequired,
abs(pointsRequired - parameter) as closest
from     the_table
order by closest
limit 1
```

Any tips? Do I have to use an [extra Query-Set](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra)? How would it look like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your SQL is correct. It should return 'level 3' if the parameter is 1999. Based on your description the SQL could be:

```
SELECT pointsRequired FROM the_table WHERE pointsRequired < parameter ORDER BY pointsRequired DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Or in Django:

```
try:
    Level.objects.filter(requiredPoints__lt=parameter).order_by('-requiredPoints')[0]
except IndexError: 
    # Do something
```